# Drop-Down Menu Causing Invalid Model State. ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a registration view in my web app. However, account registration would be unsuccessful and my drop-down menu would be outlined in red.

Here is my drop down code:

```
<div class="editor-label">  
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, "Company")  
</div>   
<div class="editor-field">  
   @Html.DropDownList("Companies", "<Select Company>")  
</div>
```

Here is my associated code in the view model:

```
[Display(Name = "Company")]    
public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
```

Here is my associated code in the controller before I return the view:

```
ViewBag.Companies = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName");
```

As I debug, I find that `ModelState.IsValid` returns false, and therefore re-returns the view (and re-sets `ViewBag.Companies` in my case).

How do I complete a successful registration? I do fill out each required field within parameters. It is not required to select company. **When I do not select a company, `ModelState.IsValid` returns true and runs through the code.** However, I would like the user to have the option to associate with his company.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error in the `ModelState`? The errors should be in the `Errors` collection in the `ModelState.Values`.

Comment: {System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)

Comment: @nemesv ^^ I'm looking into this one right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you need setting `ViewBag.Companies`, when you've got the better approach - having select list into the model? No need to use ugly ViewBag

You should have something like this

ViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
     [Display(Name = "Company")]    
     public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
     RegisterViewModel viewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
     viewModel.Companies = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName");

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in the view

```
<div class="editor-label">  
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, "Company")  
</div>   
<div class="editor-field">  
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, Model.Companies, "<Select Company>")  
</div>
```

This will bind your `CompanyId` on server correctly.

Comment: This way gives me an `InvalidOperationException`.  RegisterViewModel viewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
     viewModel.Companies = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName");

     return View(viewModel);

Comment: I have tried this way before, but was deterred from such because of a similar issue. Any help on correcting this is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you completely copied the view part that I posted? I always use this pattern and it works well.

Comment: I just retuped everything and it works for me. You must have some old code somewhere - or I do not know what's the cause of exception :)

Comment: Beautiful. I had a db insert error that was throwing the exception. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your model state will always be invalid for your dropdowns if your selected variable type is not a string. Change CompanyId to string. You can still use IEnumerable Companies {get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList is kind of weird in ASP.Net MVC3. It **will not** bind properly to an enumerable of SelectListItem. You need to store the bound, selected choice to a primitive in the model and the list of all options in a separate field.

```
<div class="editor-label">  
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, "Company")  
</div>   
<div class="editor-field">  
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, new SelectList(Model.Companies))  
</div>
```

Then, in your model, change the IEnumerable of SelectListItems to an IEnumerable of strings.

```
[Display(Name = "Company")]    
public string CompanyId { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<string> Companies { get; set; }
```

Finally, in your controller,

```
ViewBag.Companies = db.Companies;
```

Just as a sidenote, I suggest making your IEnumerable an IList instead. A dropdown menu **definitely** cares about the order in which the data is presented, so your model should reflect that.

Comment: for `public string CompanyId`, why not `int CompanyId`?