# MVC 3 DropDownList Syntax for a View/Model/Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have looked through most of the blog postings here dealing with MVC and how to use a DropDownList with little success.

I tried to mimic a post at this link but obviously not working for me: [Drop-Down Menu Causing Invalid Model State. ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689045/drop-down-menu-causing-invalid-model-state-asp-net-mvc-3)

The objective is to have a drop-down listing for a user to choose how many cars a home garage holds in the HTTP GET Create View.

The error that I am presently receiving is:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
> 'MvcPropertyManagement.Models.Property' does not contain a definition
> for 'GarageId' and no extension method 'GarageId' accepting a first
> argument of type 'MvcPropertyManagement.Models.Property' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Line 84:          Line 85:         
> Line 86:             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GarageId,
> Model.LkupGarageTypes) Line 87:
> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GarageType) Line 88:

**My Model:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MvcPropertyManagement.Models;
    using MvcPropertyManagement.Models.ViewModels;

    namespace MvcPropertyManagement.Models
    {
        public class Property
        {
            public bool Garage { get; set; }
        
            [Display(Name="Garage Capacity")]
            public string GarageType { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MvcPropertyManagement.Models;
    using MvcPropertyManagement.Models.ViewModels;

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PropertyViewModel viewModel = new PropertyViewModel();
        viewModel.LkUpGarageType = new SelectList(db.LkUpGarageTypes, "GarageTypeID",         "LkUpGarageType"); 
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**PropertyViewModel:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MvcPropertyManagement.Models;

    namespace MvcPropertyManagement.Models.ViewModels
    {
        public class PropertyViewModel
        {
            public int? GarageId { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LkUpGarageType { get; set; }        
        }
    }
```

**Create View:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GarageId, Model.LkupGarageTypes)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GarageType)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using `MvcPropertyManagement.Models.Property` as the model, not `MvcPropertyManagement.Models.ViewModels.PropertyViewModel` where GarageId is.

Try changing the model to `MvcPropertyManagement.Models.ViewModels.PropertyViewModel` on the view with:

```
@model MvcPropertyManagement.Models.ViewModels.PropertyViewModel
```

**UPDATE:**
The property class, which is used a the model:

```
public class Property
{
  public bool Garage { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Garage Capacity")]
  public string GarageType { get; set; }

  public int? GarageId { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LkUpGarageType { get; set; } 
}
```

The create action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  Property viewModel = new Property();
  viewModel.LkUpGarageType = new SelectList(db.LkUpGarageTypes, "GarageTypeID",         "LkUpGarageType"); 
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: When I changed to your @model than all my other field properties for this page lost the relationship to the Property Model.

Comment: @Shawn sounds like you are trying the use two different models on the same page which cannot be done. Then you need to at `PropertyViewModel` as a property on the `Property` class.

Comment: I'm just trying to follow another posting here on Stackoerverflow that I listed above < Drop-Down Menu Causing Invalid Model State. ASP.NET MVC 3>. The post has a model, controller, view, and an addition ViewModel class that totally lost me on the reason why.

Comment: @Shawn The view model in the other post is used as the model. To solve you problem I would add the properties from `PropertyViewModel` to `Property` or the other way around.

Comment: I've added the properties back to my Property class model but cannot figure out how to get the Get Create (Controller) to new-up a SelectList.

Comment: public IEnumerable<LkUpGarageType> LkupGarageTypes { get; set; }
    public int? GarageId { get; set; }

Comment: Controller:         public ActionResult Create()
        {

            Property viewModel = new Property();
            viewModel.LkupGarageTypes = new SelectList(db.Properties, "GarageId", "LkUpGarageType");
            return View(viewModel);
        }

Comment: You should be able to do the exact same thing as previously, just on the `Property` class as the model instead of the `PropertyViewModel`. `viewModel.LkUpGarageType = new SelectList(db.LkUpGarageTypes, "GarageTypeID",         "LkUpGarageType");`

Comment: @Shawn what type is the db variable?. Why don't you use the `db.LkUpGarageTypes`anymore?

Comment: Tried your's and received this error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcPropertyManagement.Models.LkUpGarageType>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Shawn\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcPropertyManagement\MvcPropertyManagement\Controllers\PropertyController.cs 41 41 MvcPropertyManagement

Comment: @Shawn try to change the `viewModel.LkUpGarageType` type to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: viewModel.LkupGarageType = new IEnumerable<SelectListItem>     (db.LkUpGarageTypes, "GarageTypeID", "LkUpGrageType");

Comment: @Shawn Sorry, yes that is what I meant

Comment: Nope its telling giving me Error 2 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'

Comment: @Shawn Oh, sorry try `new List<SelectListItem>`

Comment: Ok after added the new List<SelectListItem> I'm now getting this error: Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Comment: viewModel.LkupGarageTypes = new List<SelectListItem>    (db.LkUpGarageTypes, "GarageTypeID", "LkUpGrageType");

Comment: @Shawn Okay, I misunderstood you change sorry. The model should have a property like this `public IEnumerable<LkUpGarageType> LkupGarageTypes { get; set; }` and `viewModel.LkUpGarageType = new SelectList(db.LkUpGarageTypes, "GarageId", "LkUpGarageType")`

Comment: That is the way I had it from the start... Errors follow:

Comment: At the viewModel.LkUpGarageType ... Error 2 'MvcPropertyManagement.Models.Property' does not contain a definition for 'LkUpGarageType' and no extension method 'LkUpGarageType' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcPropertyManagement.Models.Property' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: On the New SelectList ... Error 1 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'

Comment: @Shawn Didn't you move the `LkUpGarageType` property to the `Property` class?

Comment: Yes from Property class  public IEnumerable<LkUpGarageType> LkupGarageTypes { get; set; }